# When to sort values

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I have Java EE project based on JSF, EJB and JPA.

When displaying data in a table i usually do the following:

`view.jsf`

```
<p:dataTable var="entry" value="#{bean.entriews}"
```

In the Backing bean the code looks as follows:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private List<Foo> entries;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        entries = FooDao.findAll();
    }

    public List<Foo> getEntries() { return entries; }
}
```

My question now is the following: When should I implement sorting? Would you sort it after the `findAll()` method? E.g.

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        entries = FooDao.findAll();
        Collections.sort(entries, MyComparator);
    }
```

Or is there any other feature in JSF I am not aware of?

Comment: `<p:dataTable>` implies that you are using PrimeFaces. Sorting (or ordering), filtering and paging should always be performed lazily (thus, not through Java code after fetching a list from the database but rather in the database itself (You are currently doing it eagerly). Memory will soon get over-flooded, if the resulting list too long). Better use PrimeFaces lazy data model as demonstrated on the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this in query? 
say:

```
FooDao.findAllByName(); // order by entery.name ASC;
FooDao.findAllByHigestPrice(); // order by entery.price ASC;
FooDao.findAllByLowestRate(); // order by entery.rate DESC;
```

You can use this approach.

**bad Approach**

In you domain class add a String type `Serial No` than compile order in java. and add `sortBy="#{row.srNo}"` in your xhtml page

Answer (score 0):

As @sarz Use primfaces datatable component "sort by"  attribute it's so far the best way to do it.  This way you may even specify the sort logic.